# dotnet sonarscanner did not find java but JAVA_HOME exists. Tried jre 11,13, 17 on ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: dotnet-framework, jvm, sonarqube

I am starting proper command

> ~/project$ /usr/bin/dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="admin" /d:sonar.password="user"

and got the java error on ubuntu 20.04.3

> SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.5.3
> Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
> Post-processing started.
> Calling the SonarScanner CLI... C
> ould not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH. T
> he SonarScanner did not complete successfully
> 20:05:32.56 Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

There are SonarQube 8.9.10 Community in docker and .net 5 global tool sonarscanner 5.5.3.

JAVA_HOME and PATH were set to the same java elf dynamic shared object with chmod +x. What's wrong? Thank you.

> java --version

> openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)

> echo $PATH

> /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

> echo $JAVA_HOME

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

Applied sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

It is default-jre.

Do I need to build C#plugin and put it into SQ docker? How can I properly make it for these versions?

Comment: both `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` should contain the path to the **directory** where the binary resides, not the binary itself.